# Hibernate Cascading within same table

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, cascading

I have a table with the below structure -

```
SampleTable (
             id pk,
             first_name,
             last_name,
             common_message1,
             common_message2
             )
```

The records will be inserted in batch in this table and will have different id, first_name, last_name but same common_message1 and common_message2.

The records will be like:

```
| 1 | Test1  |  last1  | this is same message1   | this is same message2 |        
| 2 | Test2  |  last2  | this is same message1   | this is same message2 |   
| 3 | Test3  |  last3  | this is same message1   | this is same message2 |  
| 4 | Test4  |  last4  | this is same message3   | this is same message4 |   
| 5 | Test5  |  last5  | this is same message3   | this is same message4 |
```

**NOTE - I can not normalize the table due to some design limitation in my project**

How should I handle this duplicate entries in the table, should I store them multiple times as shown above, if yes then how to insert or update so as to make sure all are same and updated properly, Or is there any other efficient way to handle such scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By updated, I assume you mean you want to make updates to the "common-message"s.

I.e. When you change the comments in one row you want it to change in all the rows with matching comments.

Your only real option is to retrieve all the rows with a WHERE clause on `common_message1` and `common_message2` then update those fields for the whole collection.

When not dealing with the messages you'd obviously want to treat them as individual entities.

I.e. When you change the `first_name` or `last_name`